# how can connect the soap webservices in symbian mobile using j2me

Tags: web-services, java-me, symbian, midlet, ksoap

I'm new in symbian mobile applications. I'm developing webservices related application in this webservices using .net webservices (ksoap). How can connect webservices in j2me midlet application in symbian mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download KSoap jar file from [here](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/). Look at the following articles for your reference.

- [Access Web services from wireless devices](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2002/jw-0823-wireless.html)
- [Mobile Web Services with kSOAP](http://java.sys-con.com/node/37193)

Look at this discussion, [Ksoap / j2me / .Net Web Service.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/221343/Web-Services/java/Ksoap-me-Net-Web-Service)